# WSO2 EMM 2.0 iOS Enrollment Error

Tags: ios, ssl

I am receiving the below error when I try to enter my domain, username and password during the iOS enrollment process. I have everything pointing to the domain name of the server, not the IP address. I don't know why its istrying to use the IP to enroll the device as everything is changed to domain names in the config files.

Does anybody have ideas?

Thank you!

```
[2016-04-15 10:46:27,836] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.ios.util.OAuthUtils}- 
Error occurred while sending 'Post' request due to failure of server connectionjavax.net.ssl.SSLException: 
hostname in certificate didn't match: <IP> != <hostname>
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:227)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:147)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating SSL certificate then you need to have the domain name as the common name. Also make sure you change config.json files accordingly with the domain name specially when it comes to EMM Jaggeryapps. Also in cdm-config.xml.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have changed config.json and cdm-config.xml to the domain name. But it remains the same error(T . T). Any other ideas?